# Convert PGP key to X.509?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, x.509, openpgp

Can I convert a PGP key to X.509, using OpenSSL or GNUPG?

Aren't these only container/wrapper formats?

Comment: x.509 is a container format for certificates, and PGP keys are specially encoded keys.  There not transformable into one another…. Specifically because you need a key container. Not a certificate container. And one of the same type as the PGP key is…. Such as a RSA container. (That can be done….but why would you want that?)

Answer (score 3):

> Can I convert a PGP key to X.509, using OpenSSL or GNUPG?

The GnuPG software, originally developed for PGP, in recent years also supports SMIME which uses X.509/PKIX, and OpenSSH.

1. given an *RSA* private PGP key (which PGP and GnuPG call secret for historical reasons) you can convert it to an SMIME key and export that as PKCS8 X509 and/or PKCS12 (which is a wrapper for both PKCS8 and X509). See
   [Create CSR for S/MIME certificate from existing OpenPGP key pair](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238641/create-csr-for-s-mime-certificate-from-existing-openpgp-key-pair)
   [Extract OpenPGP secret key material to use as X.509 root CA's key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/259534/extract-openpgp-secret-key-material-to-use-as-x-509-root-cas-key)
   https://superuser.com/questions/435321/how-can-i-export-public-keys-in-pem-format-with-gnupg
2. recent `gpg --export-ssh-key` exports a PGP *public* key in the format(s) used by OpenSSH, and OpenSSH (not OpenSSL) can then convert these formats to X.509 SPKI (but not a full certificate) with `ssh-keygen -e -m PKCS8` (note this is NOT PKCS8 even though OpenSSH calls it so). See the superuser Q from #1 above and
   https://superuser.com/questions/360507/are-gpg-and-ssh-keys-interchangable

Also, as I noted on those and some similar Qs, you can *write* Java code for any and all conversions between these key formats using the BouncyCastle libraries, which support the PKCS and X509-based formats used by OpenSSL and the PGP formats -- and in recent years the OpenSSH formats to boot.

> Aren't these only container/wrapper formats?

Not at all.

- SSH protocol defines XDR-based wire formats for *transmitting* publickeys. OpenSSH, mentioned above, has for decades stored publickeys as a base64 encoding of the wire format(s), and since 6.5 (2014) defines a privatekey file format similarly based on XDR. A variant of the publickey format, with added linebreaks and (minimal) metadata, is standardized as RFC4716, but little used.
- the XML standards for signature and encryption -- XMLdsig and XMLenc, together XMLsec -- define and use XML-based key formats. These were popular for a while as SOAP, but now survive mostly in SAML, although I believe there are still some EDI applications.
- the JOSE (Json signing and encryption) standards define Json-based key formats called JWK -- Json Web Key -- used mostly in conjuction with JWT -- Json Web Token(s).
- the COSE (CBOR signing and encryption) standards, derived from JOSE, define key formats with the same content as JWK but encoded differently.

And I'm sure there are more. Edits welcome.